# image click to delete via ok or cancel HTML Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an image i want to use as a delete connection for a table row in my connections.

i want to integrate a confirm delete message box using javascript.

Here is the table row:

```
<td>
    <input type="image" name="submit" src="static/img/32/critical.png" alt="Delete Connection" onclick="(<%# Eval("id").ToString%>);clearText(<%= result.ClientID%>); CopyId(<%# Eval("id").ToString%>); return Message(<%# Eval("id").ToString%>)" />
</td>
```

and here is the script:

```
<script>
    function Message() {
        var txt;
        var ok = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this connection");
        if (ok == true) {
            return true;
            txt = "Connection Deleted!";
            (<%# Eval("id").ToString%>);clearText(<%= result.ClientID%>); CopyId(<%# Eval("id").ToString%>);
        } else { 
            return false; 
            txt = "Cancelled";
        }
        document.getElementById("PopUp").innerHTML = txt;
    }
</script>
```

and

```
<p id="PopUp"></p>
```

at the moment when i click the image it just deletes the row and connection without asking me. I would like it to ask for confirmation and act accordingly.

if true then run the delete and if no then cancel.

struggling a bit as new to this so any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try the following code

```
    <script>
         function Message() {
             var txt ="";
             var ok = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this connection");
             if (ok) {
                txt = "Connection Deleted!";
                // your code here

             } else { 
               txt = "Cancelled";

             }
             document.getElementById("PopUp").innerHTML = txt;
          }
    </script>
```

Comment: I tried your code but it still just deletes the row without any message box

Comment: because when you return true or false in `if` then it not run to `document.getElementById("PopUp").innerHTML = txt;`

Comment: ok so far so good, its now working functionally, i just had to tweak it slightly and add id into the Messaage(id) as so.

Now i have it doing what i want i just need to sort the messaging out, i have no return message after cancel or confirm is clicked. I think i need to move the getElementById or write an extra bit to return my messages? any idea s?

Comment: got it all working, thank you Tuan-IT, marked as answer for helpful advice